# How to split an array of a strings?

Tags: c#

I have a file with the contents:

```
Message1 : Some Random String 1
Message2 : Some Random String 2
Message3 : Some Random String 3
Message4 : Some Random String 4
Message5 : Some Random String 5
```

I am trying to figure out how I can split each line after the ':' character.

I've tried this so far, but I am not getting the desired output:

```
string splitConfig() {
    string split = ":";  
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("config_file.cfg");
    string linesJoined = lines[0] + "\n" + lines[1] + "\n" + lines[2] + "\n" + lines[3] + "\n" + lines[4];  
    string output = linesJoined.Substring(linesJoined.IndexOf(split) + split.Length);
    return output;
}
```

This just returns

```
"Some Random String 1
Message2 : Some Random String 2
Message3 : Some Random String 3
Message4 : Some Random String 4
Message5 : Some Random String 5"
```

But I'm looking for an output of:

```
{
    "Some Random String 1", 
    "Some Random String 2", 
    "Some Random String 3", 
    "Some Random String 4", 
    "Some Random String 5"
}
```

Comment: @user3175478 in all seriousness, your question is getting downvoted because 1) it isn't clear what you are asking and 2) you aren't showing code of your attempt + any problems it is giving you.

Comment: made it clear for you. added my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here's another solution, just for fun:

```
var result = 
    input.Split(new[] { " : ", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
         .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1);
```

---

Given your update, it appears you're already reading the file into an array of strings representing each line, so all you have to do is now get the part after the `:` for each line. Your algorithm isn't far off, but try using a little Linq with it, like this:

```
string Char = ":";  
string[] Messages = File.ReadAllLines(@"MessageMenu.cfg");

var Output = Messages.Select(s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf(Char) + Char.Length));
```

Note that this will not return a single string, but an [`IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), representing all the message strings from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
var result = input.Split('\n')
                  .Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(":") + 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are a bit tough to understand, but I believe this will give you what you're after:

```
var messages = input.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(l => l.Split(' : ')[1])
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
string sourceText = @"
  Message1 : Some Random String 1
  Message2 : Some Random String 2
  Message3 : Some Random String 3
  Message4 : Some Random String 4
  Message5 : Some Random String 5
  " ;
Regex rx = new Regex( @"^\s*(.*?)\s+:\s+(.*?)\s+$" , RegexOptions.Multiline ) ; // using non-greedy accumulation here (.*?) to reduce backtracking
Dictionary<string,string> messages = rx
                                     .Matches(sourceText)
                                     .Cast<Match>()
                                     .ToDictionary(
                                        m => m.Groups[1].Value ,
                                        m => m.Groups[2].Value
                                     ) ;
```